# 100% width header and footer bur fixed content with 100% height

Tags: html, css, height

I have a structure like:

```
HEADER -> 100% width -> variable height

CONTENT -> 1080px width -> I NEED TO FILL THE PAGE HEIGHT WHEN SHORT CONTENT

FOOTER -> 100% WIDTH -> 230 px height
```

I saw people using the CALC from CSS.
But in my case, I don't have a fixed height for my header, so that math doesn't work.

Any ideas?

I got this code from a website and put some colors to illustrate: http://pastebin.com/kyd35zp6

I need the red div to fill the page.

Any help is good!

**UPDATE**

I forgot to mention that is a sticky footer

I need something like this: http://maujor.com/tutorial/rodape/rodape-fixo-no-fim-da-pagina-7.html

But i need the 100% width header and 100% width footer.
The content must look like that, a white "dash" with a different background around it.

Answer (score 0):

wrap `HEADER` `CONTENT` `FOOTER` inside a `#container`....then

SET - `html,body, #container{height:100%;}`

after that, if you set `CONTENT` to `{height:100%}` it would work

[try it here](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ep27/)

Comment: I forgot to mention my footer is like sticky footer, always on bottom. I nedd something like this but with 100% header and footer: http://maujor.com/tutorial/rodape/rodape-fixo-no-fim-da-pagina-7.html.

Comment: @KauêPorte : check if you can work with this fiddle, fluid header and fixed footer with content taking all middle area => http://jsfiddle.net/6Ep27/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
}
#header
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
#container
{
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1080px;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}
#footer
{
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 70px;
    background: green;
    color: white;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/46xF5/15/)

Comment: Not there yet. In high resolutions it miss a piece of the content.
What I need is more like this, but with 100% header and footer, I need content to have that "dash" space with background around: http://maujor.com/tutorial/rodape/rodape-fixo-no-fim-da-pagina-7.html

Comment: @KauêPorte : check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/46xF5/16/ . if you don't want fixed sticky footer remove this two lines (position: fixed; bottom: 0;) from #footer styles..

Comment: same thing. Works "right" if I have a lot of contents, but with few lines, it misses a piece. You can test in high res here: http://www.infobyip.com/testwebsiteresolution.php